# drupal 7 tag clouds http 500.19 error

Tags: sql-server, iis, drupal, drupal-7

I am ASP.NET/C#.NET developer who is new to Drupal 7. We have installed Drupal 7 on a WISP stack (Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8.5, SQL Server Express 2012, PHP 5.4). The problem we are encountering is as follows: I installed the Tag Clouds (https://www.drupal.org/project/tagclouds) module and then try to configure it. When I saved the configuration the Drupal website suffered

> a HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

As a result I cannot browse to the website now. I cannot access the Admin menu to remove the Tag Clouds module.

I have tried to resolve the issue by following the instructions in this MS Support article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942055

I checked Windows Event Viewer Application Log when the HTTP Error 500.19 occurred and saw the below Warning:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.:

```
SELECT TOP(12) td.[tid] AS [tid], td.[vid] AS [vid], td.[name] AS [name], td.[description] AS [description], COUNT(*) AS count, max(n.nid) AS nid, COUNT(*) AS _field_0, td.tid AS _field_1, td.vid AS _field_2, td.name AS _field_3, td.description HAVING COUNT(*) &gt; 0 AS _field_4
FROM 
{taxonomy_term_data} td
INNER JOIN {taxonomy_index} tn ON td.tid = tn.tid
INNER JOIN {node} n ON tn.nid = n.nid
WHERE (  ([td].[vid] IN  (:db_condition_placeholder_0)) AND ([n].[status] = :db_condition_placeholder_1)  )
GROUP BY td.tid, td.vid, td.name, td.description HAVING COUNT(*) &gt; 0
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC; Array
(
    [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; 1
    [:db_condition_placeholder_1] =&gt; 1
)
```

in `tagclouds_get_tags() (line 275 of F:\Inetpub\wwwroot\acquia-drupal7\sites\all\modules\tagclouds\tagclouds.module).`

Any help with this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to disable the module so that your site works again. Use the SQL found here at https://www.drupal.org/node/157632.

The module appears to use the proper db_select() function, so I'm not entirely sure why SQL Server doesn't like the syntax.

Which version of Drupal are you using? It's possible that a more recent release has fixed the MSSQL driver.

Comment: The link you provided are for MySQL commands. Are these relevant for MS SQL Server too? I moved the tagclouds module out of the \sites\all\modules directory and the site was then accessible again. We are using Drupal 7. Do you know if the "Drupal 7 driver for SQL Server and SQL Azure" (https://www.drupal.org/project/sqlsrv) module would solve the underlying SQL Server exception cited above? I want to be able to install the tagclouds module but am afraid to do so now. Thanks. Ross.

Comment: Those are absolutely standard SQL commands, that would work on hundreds of different SQL DBs. I'd be very surprised if MSSQL Server couldn't run them. The only possibility I can see is if you require a non-standard syntax for table or field names (like "[tablename].[fieldname]"). But I don't think you do.